# How to translate "trade mark" or "brand" (whether registered or not)?

Tags: single-word-requests, disambiguation

What is the Esperanto word for "trade mark" or "brand"?

[In ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/mark.html#mark.0o) I found "komerca marko" and "fabrikmarko" that don't seem to be further explained there, but might be fitting. Though:

- Can e.g. "komerca marko" be used for brands that are (actually or perceived) non-commercial? (e.g. WWF, Greenpeace, GNU, Linux)
- Can "fabrikmarko" be used for marks applied to non-tangible "products"? (e.g. WWF, Greenpeace, GNU, Linux)

Are different Esperanto words to be used depending on whether the trademark/brand is registered, or is there an Esperanto term that (like German "Marke" when not applying to stamps or similar) captures both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oni ankaŭ povas uzi la vorton "varmarko" kiel en la frazo: "« Transilien », same kiel « TER » aŭ « TGV », estas varmarko apartenanta al SNCF." (eltirita el la artikolo https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transilien el Vikipedio).